# ReloadingPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Tags: java, spring

For some reason the ReloadablePropertiesFactoryBean doens't seem to do what I expect. When I change a property in the test.properties file I get a log message saying:

```
9979 [timer] INFO com.krest.core.properties.ReloadablePropertiesFactoryBean - Reloading Properties...
```

But for some reason nothing happens. The old property value is still set on my test bean. Does anybody know why this is? I use Spring 3 and my configuration looks like this:

```
<bean id="configproperties"
    class="com.krest.core.properties.ReloadablePropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="location"
        value="classpath:test.properties" />
</bean>

<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="com.krest.core.properties.ReloadingPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="properties" ref="configproperties" />
    <property name="reloadingPlaceholderPrefix" value="rel{" />
    <property name="reloadingPlaceholderSuffix" value="}" />
</bean>

<bean id="mybean" class="nl.mycompany.TestBean">
    <property name="message" value="rel{timer-delay}" />
</bean>

<!-- regularly reload property files. -->
<bean id="timer" class="org.springframework.scheduling.timer.TimerFactoryBean">
    <property name="scheduledTimerTasks">
        <bean id="reloadProperties"
            class="org.springframework.scheduling.timer.ScheduledTimerTask">
            <property name="period" value="1000" />
            <property name="runnable">
                <bean class="com.krest.core.properties.ReloadConfiguration">
                    <property name="reconfigurableBeans">
                        <list>
                            <ref bean="configproperties" />
                        </list>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Any luck finding the reason of this issue?

Comment: Consider https://github.com/UniconLabs/springframework-addons/blob/master/src/main/java/net/unicon/springframework/addons/properties/ReloadingPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java and https://github.com/knightliao/disconf/blob/master/disconf-client/src/main/java/com/baidu/disconf/client/addons/properties/ReloadingPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java